# В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект при добавлении данных

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
  public class KeyGroup
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public bool used { get; set; }
        public List<string> url { get; set; }
    }
```

Создаю экземпляр класса.

```
KeyGroup keyGroup = new KeyGroup();
keyGroup.key = "ya.ru"; // это работает
keyGroup.url.AddRange(list); // здесь ошибку выдает
keyGroup.url=list; // А так работает
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поля класса ссылочного типа инициализируются компилятором значением `null`.

```
public class KeyGroup
{
  public string key { get; set; }
  public bool used { get; set; }
  public List<string> url { get; set; }
  public KeyGroup()
  {
    url = new List<string>();
  }
}
```